# How can I improve this question to be re-opened: Is HTML Turing Complete?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

I recently asked this question: [Is HTML Turing Complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30719221/1766230) which was closed as being "Too Broad". I've edited the question a few times in hopes that it could be re-opened, but no luck so far. I'm hoping the community can help provide some tips on how it can be improved.

Interestingly there is an almost identical question, but relating to CSS instead of HTML: [Is CSS turing complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2497146/1766230) which has received four good answers, two of which have hundreds of up-votes. My train of thought...

- If the CSS question is valid, why is the HTML question not valid?
- ...If neither one is valid, should the CSS question also be closed for the same reasons?
- ...If both should be closed, doesn't it hurt the SO community to close questions that are well-received and apparently useful?

Comment: The CSS question is 5 years old, probably not a good reference point

Comment: But voting to reopen yours, seeing as it has a fine answer

Comment: seems like it reopened

Comment: Thank you @Pekka웃 ! Just because a question is old, doesn't mean it's not valid, does it? I personally found the CSS question to be a great one.

Comment: Just because a question is old also does not automatically mean it's valid *today*. The bar has been raised over the years.

Comment: Why exactly did you ask two meta questions about reopening your one linked question?

Comment: @JK. This one is specifically about improving the specific question. The other one was meant to be a more generic question about re-opening questions and dealing with close tags. Sorry for any confusion.